# Using "standard" "singleTop" "singleTask" and "singleInstance" to control tab-based android application

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I have an android application. The activities form a complete graph: in other words, you can go from any activity to any other activity through calls to `startActivity`. **Furthermore**, my application is tab-based, with four tabs. This means there are four entry points to my activity graph. Now no matter where a user is in the app, the option to click on a tab is present; an action that would call `startActivity` for the tab target.

I want each activity that is associated with a tab item to be, essential, an anchor activity so that if I click on a tab, every activity that proceeded from it is deleted and it is now the top. I hope someone can help me with this. There is one complication that I see immediately. If I am on TabCat, I can click on TabDog to start DogActivity. Here both CatActivity and DogActivity are anchor activities. So neither should delete the other.

For reference, the Instagram app is a tab-based app. And it does follow the design I just described. Any ideas how I might use any, or a combination, of ["standard" "singleTop"  "singleTask"  "singleInstance"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) to solve this problem? Again my four tab activities are CatActivity, DogActivity, MouseActivity, BirActivity. In addition to those, I have 16 more activities.

If you want to think of this as automata theory, think of this finite state machine as having four different start states, sixteen addition states, and the start states can be reached from other states.

Comment: You might want to use fragments and only a single activity.

Comment: I think the downvote means this question is way above somebody's intellectual pay grade. :)

Comment: actually iOS seems to handle this quite well. In iOS when you create a tab-based application, the system basically treats your app as four apps in one (if you have four tabs). It's basically **incidental** that the four tabs access the same graph of MVCs (or Activities for android). So that seems to be what you are looking for. I would be interested in a sound solution to this. This seems to be a reasonable thing to expect from android. Having said that, this may not be neccessary. Just let the chips fall where they may. Of course that's easier said than done. But it's a thought.

Comment: You simply can call finish():

Intent intent = new Intent(...);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); //close current activity. But I think you need to read a bit about android tasks and activities. For example, here: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode